# My Edit action wasn't recorded for a review

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, improve-edit

I reviewed a couple suggested edits this morning here on Meta, but one of my actions didn't get recorded.

I decided to [improve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/16609/revisions) [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13483) and also marked it as not helpful because it didn't attempt to improve that run-on sentence of a title that made no sense (too minor). My edit was applied successfully (yay) and Community rejected the suggestion as well (yay). But I never got any credit for the review with an **Edit** action listed there (not yay).

What happened?

Comment: Interesting. It shows up under your Revision activity, but not Review.